# How to import different styles from different files in a component in NextJS 13?

Tags: next.js, import, sass

I have imported styles from the media-wrapper module and am using the mediaWrapper class, now I want to use a class from another scss module, how do I accomplish that?

```js
import styles from '../../../styles/media-wrapper.module.scss'
import Image from 'next/image'

export const VideoCard = ({ size, video_data }) => {
  const videoLeague = video_data.leagues.nodes[0]?.name

  return (
    <div className={`${size == 'big' ? 'col-span-3 pb-[60.26%]' : 'col-span-2 pb-[92.86%]'} ${styles.mediaWrapper} w-full rounded-[1rem] overflow-hidden`}>
      <Image 
      src={video_data.featuredImage.node.sourceUrl}
      />
      <div className='absolute top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 flex flex-col items-start justify-end w-full p-8'>
        {
          videoLeague &&
          <span className='rounded-[0.5rem] text-primary-watercourseGreen bg-primary-washMe py-[0.625rem] px-[0.875rem] inline-block mb-4'>{videoLeague}</span>
        }
        <span className='text-2xl leading-[1.875rem]'>{video_data.title}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I couldn't try anything since I couldn't find documentation that would help me with this problem.